# C++ conversion operators

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I know the deal .The compiler tries to convert one object into the other objects's type with the help of conversion operator .Two ways to do this .Constructor (Converts a class to the other) or conversion operator .So , this one is just to test if I am thorough with the concepts .The code below gives the error

```
using namespace std ;
class A
{
    int i ;
    public:
            A(int a=0){this->i=a;}
            A operator+(const A& b){
                    A c ;
                    return c(this->i+b.i);
            }
            void show()
            {
                    cout<<i<<endl;
            }
 };
int main()
{
    A a1(1),a2(2),a3;
    a3=a2+a1;
    a3.show();
    return 0;
 }
```

I guess the error is in the operator + .When I try to assign A(i) .There is no match for an operator which could create an A from an int .

But Then I see this A's constructor lurking behind .It can convert an int into an A .Suppose , it does convert int into an A.Then , the call becomes A(B) .This is equivalent to the copy constructor .Hence , this call should work .But it doesn't .All in all , am pretty confused .

Please help .

Comment: Paste the error message.

Comment: Make those methods `const` (after fixing the errors pointed out in answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In these two lines you are telling the compiler to construct an A object with the default constructor, then call its nonexistent operator () (int) and return its return value:

```
                A c ;
                return c(this->i+b.i);
```

Use either

```
A c(i + b.i);
return c;
```

or

```
return A(i + b.i);
```

On a side note, an example for an implicit conversion operator, for your class:

```
operator int () const
{
    return i;
}
```

But their use smells like bad design, and can cause bad stuff to happen, like implicit conversion to bool or a pointer. Use something else instead, like an `int toInt () const` member function.

Comment: But when making the call 
`return c(this->i+b.i);` , why isn't the constructor get called and try to change int into the A type and then call the copy constructor ??
like in the below fragment 
`class BigBuffer
{
public:
 BigBuffer(int initialValue)
   { memset(buffer, initialValue, sizeof(buffer)); }
private:
 char buffer[65536];
};

extern void Foo(const BigBuffer& o);
void oops()
{
 Foo(3);
}`
This should follow the same format i suppose !!

Comment: As I said, you are not calling a constructor or a function, you are trying to call `operator ()` on your c object, which does not exist. They are completely unrelated things.
If you had an `operator () (int)`, it would accept A objects as well (unless the constructor is `explicit`), but its behaviour would not be what you wanted in your first example. It might not even return A objects. Using an A constructor is the proper way to do your first example. In your second example, you are calling a function, not the nonexistent `operator ()`, hence the implicit conversion works there.

Comment: Can you give me a good resource for these type of questions .I seem pretty confused with this  "implicit conversion" thing .I know i should make all the cosntructors explicit , but for the fun of knowing it , any good resource ?? Some internet forum etc .Article .(Please , don't say bjarne strustroup )

Comment: Check out the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/), it's very useful.